# Node.Js Middleware next

Tags: node.js, express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having a hard time trying to understand ‘next/next()’ in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710669/having-a-hard-time-trying-to-understand-next-next-in-express-js)

I have the following code in my app.js to handle request

```
app.get ('/' , routes.index);
require('./services/Category')(app);
```

I have Category file with the required functionalities and it works fine. But when I explore about Middleware concept there is a specific key word called "next" which is being passed in every method. How does "next" works ? What it carries ?

Comment: @scriptfromscratch -I understand that next is a call back method and next () will call the next middleware that been included in the configuration (app.configure). So if I want to keep any validation for all the end points (token validation) I have to keep the validation in separate middleware and perform is my understanding is correct ?

Comment: Another explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next