# ExpressJs - where express.static(__dirname) point to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
port = process.argv[2] || 8000;

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(
        "/", 
        express.static(__dirname) 
    );
});
app.listen(port);
```

I removed this piece of line below and i got an error while loading localhost

```
app.configure(function () {
        app.use(
            "/", 
            express.static(__dirname) 
        );
    });
```

1. What does the app.use method do?.
2. What does the express.static method do? and where does the __dirname points to?.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**What does the app.use method do?.**

Express has a `Middleware` which can be configured using app.configure where we can invoke use `app.use()`. `Middleware` is used by routes, lets take i called 
`app.use(express.bodyParser())` which added this layer to my `Middleware` stack. This ensures that for all incoming requests the server parses the body which `Middleware` takes cares of. This happens because we added the layer to our `Middleware` .

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/proto.html#app.use

**What does the express.static method? and where does the __dirname points to?.**

The code creates an Express server, adds the static `Middleware` and finally starts listening on port `3000` or provided port.

```
app.use(
     "/",
     express.static(__dirname)
);
```

The above code is equivalent to below, which you make you understand.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

The static middleware handles serving up the content from a directory. In this case the 'root' directory is served up and any content (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) will be available. 
This means if the root directory looks like:

```
index.html
js - folder
css - folder
```

For more references on the same topic, below are stackoverflow links associated.

- [Express app.use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009415/express-app-use)
- [What does middleware and app.use actually mean in Expressjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337572/can-someone-explain-what-middleware-is-and-what-app-use-actually-means?lq=1)

Answer (score 24):

In Node, the `__dirname` is a global object that contains the name of the directory that the executing script resides from. For example, if you are running `node script.js` from `/home/user/env`, then `__dirname` will contain `` `/home/user/env ``.

The method `app.use()` is a function inherited from the [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) framework, which is the framework Express is written on. The method attaches a middleware function to the application stack, which runs every time Express receives a request.

The code you showed mounts a static server to the path `/` that reads from the directory the script is executing from:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

If you were to change the path to `/path`, then the static file server will serve static files from that path instead. If you specify no path, then `/` is used by default.

As for what `express.static()` does itself, it accepts a path and returns a middleware function that listens on requests. This is how the middleware works:

1. Check if the request method is `GET` or `HEAD`. If neither, ignore the request.
2. Parse the path and pause the request.
3. Check if there is a default redirect. If so, redirect with a `HTTP 303`.
4. Define the handlers for if a directory or error is encountered.
5. Pass everything to the [send](https://github.com/visionmedia/send) module for MIME identification and file serving.

Here is the `static()` middleware source from Connect for reference:

```
exports = module.exports = function(root, options) {
  options = options || {};

  // root required
  if (!root) throw new Error('static() root path required');

  // default redirect
  var redirect = false !== options.redirect;

  return function staticMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    if ('GET' != req.method && 'HEAD' != req.method) return next();
    var path = parse(req).pathname;
    var pause = utils.pause(req);

    function resume() {
      next();
      pause.resume();
    }

    function directory() {
      if (!redirect) return resume();
      var pathname = url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname;
      res.statusCode = 303;
      res.setHeader('Location', pathname + '/');
      res.end('Redirecting to ' + utils.escape(pathname) + '/');
    }

    function error(err) {
      if (404 == err.status) return resume();
      next(err);
    }

    send(req, path)
      .maxage(options.maxAge || 0)
      .root(root)
      .index(options.index || 'index.html')
      .hidden(options.hidden)
      .on('error', error)
      .on('directory', directory)
      .pipe(res);
  };
};
```