# How use next() properly in routes (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var s_bookingController = require('s/controllers);

app.get('/dashboard/:page/:param', s_bookingController.index)
app.get('/dashboard/show/:id', s_bookingController.show);
```

Controllers:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    var page = parseInt(req.param("id"));

    data = {};
    data.page = page;
    data.nextPage = page + 1;
    data.prevPage = page - 1;

    MyModel.find().sort('brand').skip((page-1)*11).limit(11).exec(function(err, result) {
        res.render('index', {
            data: data,
            booking: result,
        });
    });
};
```

And

```
exports.show = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.param("id");

    res.send(id);
};
```

I'm using this controllers, but there is something wrong with the code of the `exports.index`, because it's stuck in the code.

If I change the routes to:

```
app.get('/dashboard/:page', s_bookingController.index)
```

(Note that I'm take off the second parameter that I was passing)

the show will work, but if I use the second parameter, the show will not run, it will be stuck in the index page.

Why is this? I was wondering if I need use the `next();`.

Comment: Put the `show` route above the first one

Comment: missing a tag? (node doesn't define app or routes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having a hard time trying to understand 'next/next()' in express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710669/having-a-hard-time-trying-to-understand-next-next-in-express-js)

Comment: is working @VsevolodGoloviznin .. can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding my comment:

You should have the following order of the routes:

```
app.get('/dashboard/show/:id', s_bookingController.show);
app.get('/dashboard/:page/:param', s_bookingController.index);
```

Express routing requires that a more specific route should be placed above the more general one.

The `/dashboard/show/:id` is more specific in this case as `/dashboard/:page/:param` covers it, so that `/dashboard/show` is handled by it. When the route is handled next routes are not executed.

Comment: I understood.. but, what are the criteria?? Why the show is more specific @VsevolodGoloviznin ??