# Where are get, post methods defined in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm unable to find the code of `get` or `post` methods. I haven't found them in expressjs lib folder, so it's probably that they are present in one of the js files the `Router` requires.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Blah = require('../modules/Blah');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Blah.foo(req, res);
});
```

I need it to find out where the `next` parameter is passed to that callback function above, because it has to be done by ExpressJS framework under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Express uses the [methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/methods) module to dynamically attach http verbs to the router :

lib/router/index.js :

```
// create Router#VERB functions

methods.concat('all').forEach(function(method){

  proto[method] = function(path){

    var route = this.route(path)

    route[method].apply(route, slice.call(arguments, 1));

    return this;

  };

});
```

Comment: Plus one for posting your answer faster than me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

See the answer by KeatsPeeks for more details. Here are some links to specific parts of the source code that might be helpful:

- `get` and `post` methods are defined in the `methods` module here:
  https://github.com/jshttp/methods/blob/master/index.js#L14-L15
- Here in `lib/applciation.js` the `.METHOD` calls for them are delegated to `router.METHOD`:
  https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L471-L484
- The rest is in `lib/router/index.js`:
  https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L506-L513
- And in `lib/router/route.js` - search for "`methods`" in:
  https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js

Comment: Thanks! Even though I have all this now, I was unable to find exact line where the callback method is called from post method (I mean this callback function- `function(req, res, next)` here: `router.post('/', function(req, res, next)`.)

Comment: In short, I'd like to see the source of the `next` method (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710669/having-a-hard-time-trying-to-understand-next-next-in-express-js )